# "pod try" returns error "unknown option --unshallow"

Tags: cocoapods, google-maps-sdk-ios

I was following GoogleMaps SDK for iOS instructions, and I just installed cocoapods with

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Then I tried

```
$ pod try GoogleMaps
```

Then I got this error message

```
Updating spec repositories
Performing a deep fetch of the `master` specs repo to improve future  performance
[!] /usr/local/git/bin/git fetch --unshallow

error: unknown option `unshallow'
```

Not sure where I can edit to remove this --unshallow option.

I searched around but didn't find any other people mentioning this. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

For me the error was because I needed to [**upgrade git**](https://git-scm.com/). I found this:

> The `--unshallow` option was introduced in Git 1.8.2 and your version of 
>   Git appears to be older than that
>   [source](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-building/cS5WP43W2cc/QLa9Hf72V1MJ)

Comment: This was a huge help in solving another problem. I was trying to install cocoapods for an iOS project and was seeing "unknown option -C". This tipped me off that it could be the same outdated git issue. Thanks!